# How to setup Akka Cluster in multiple machine?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I have looked into offical Akka documentation and I confuse. I follow this [link](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.3/java/cluster-usage.html) and I used the same application.conf as like that and change the seed-node into my another machine ip.

```
akka {

actor.provider = "akka.cluster.ClusterActorRefProvider"

remote.netty.tcp.port=0
remote.netty.tcp.hostname=127.0.0.1

cluster {
seed-nodes = [
  "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@slave01:2551",
  "akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@slave02:2552"]

auto-down-unreachable-after = 10s
}

extensions = ["akka.cluster.client.ClusterClientReceptionist"]

persistence {
journal.plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb-shared"
journal.leveldb-shared.store {
  # DO NOT USE 'native = off' IN PRODUCTION !!!
  native = off
  dir = "target/shared-journal"
}
snapshot-store.plugin = "akka.persistence.snapshot-store.local"
snapshot-store.local.dir = "target/snapshots"
}

}
```

The problem is that it's said it's unreachable and connection refused. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure connection isn't blocked by firewall on the two hosts?  I would first check whether both slave01 and slave02 are remotely reachable using `telnet` at their corresponding port (e.g. `telnet slave02 2552`).  And in case slave01 and slave02 are hostnames or FQDN, they would need to be mapped to corresponding IP addresses in `/etc/hosts` or DNS, accordingly.

Comment: I did disable the firewall. It's still give me connection refused. However, the ssh to slave01 is working. @Leo C

Comment: Are you able to get response when telneting to port 2551 on slave1 (and 2552 on slave2) from another host?  I would also verify (with `ps`, etc), that the Akka cluster node is up and running on both hosts.

Comment: No, I tried it. It still doesn't work. Am I understand correctly that in both master and slave01 need to have same file and path which mean application.conf is in both machine. Is that correct?

Comment: Both are seed nodes (not master/slave) for any additional nodes to join the cluster, hence can be started up in any order.  And yes, you need the application along with configuration file in a similar environment/file structure running on each of the hosts.

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Also in application.conf of 1st machine and 2nd machine need to be the same? like akka.tcp://ClusterSystem@slave01:2551. Do i need to include the master ip? in both machine?

Comment: Yes, each of the two hosts that serve as the seed nodes should have a copy of the application.conf consisting of both IP addresses or hostnames.